# Can not authorization by uber api, I have server_token, client_id and client_secret, how send request?

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, uber-api

Why do I get the error request uri?

https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=".$settings['global']['clientId'].'&clientSecret="'.$settings['global']['clientSecret'].'&scope=all_trips&redirect_uri=http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'token.php

Answer (score 0):

- For the [GET /oauth/v2/authorize](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-one-authorize) endpoint the *clientSecret* parameter that you send is not required and may interfere with some parameter validation on their backend.
  The parameters you need to pass are:

  > response_type
  >   client_id
  >   scope
  >   state
  >   redirect_uri

  Read the above URL to understand what each parameter means.
- Make sure the base of the URI you send in the query parameter redirect_uri to the GET https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize endpoint matches the one defined in the [Uber Developers Dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard) for your app, Authorizations tab.

  As the docs for the [authorize OAuth request](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-one-authorize) says:

  > redirect_uri (optional)   The URI we will redirect back to after an
  >   authorization by the resource owner.
  >       The base of the URI must match the redirect_uri used during the registration of your application.

  The redirect URL can be:

  1. localhost

     > http://::1
     >   http://127.0.0.1
     >   http://localhost
  2. any HTTPS:// URL

     > https://
  3. a custom scheme

     > custom-scheme://
- Make sure your redirect URI is [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) enabled

  According to the same [authorization and authentication documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication):

  ```
  The Uber API implements the OAuth 2.0 standard for secure authentication and authorization.  
  All communication with our servers must be over SSL (https://).
  ```

  For getting a TLS certificate at no cost for your domain I recommend [Let's Encrypt Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt)

Comment: In API DOCS has this option, but this not work, 
`
YOUR_SERVER_TOKEN has in  
curl -H 'Authorization: Token YOUR_SERVER_TOKEN' \
'https://api.uber.com/v1/1'
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Token '.$this->server_token) );
https://api.uber.com/v1.1/history 
return  NULL`

Comment: The [GET /v1.1/history](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v11-history) API endpoint requires an *OAuth 2.0 bearer token with the history_lite scope.* If your access token was not granted using that scope you will get 401 Unauthorized error. Also keep in mind that **a bearer token is different from a server token.** For the history endpoint you need a Bearer token obtained from a successful user [authentication and authorization](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#oauth-20). So you have to do curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->access_token) );

Comment: Ok, I must send code from authorize by POST method
$result = postKeys("https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token",
 array(
  'client_secret'=>$settings['global']['client_secret'],
  'client_id'=>$settings['global']['client_id'],
  'grant_type'=> 'authorization_code',
  'code'=> substr($_GET["code"], 0, -2),
  ), array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
);
If I do this, I return invalid_grant
http://devs.monomax.lclients.ru/token.php?code=7eJeL3kVWpBMFqMZRLD6AY4CItB2AC#_

Comment: Make sure you are also sending the redirect_uri parameter, which must have the same base as the one defined in the [Uber Developers Dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard). If you don't have a redirect_uri defined, make sure to define it!

Comment: I copy this redirect_uri from dashboard, this can not be different
  'redirect_uri'=> 'http://localhost/location.php',

Answer (score 0):

- > 1) надо работать с например http://localhost/loacation.php( )
- > 2) не надо вырезать лишние символы из переменной code

  require_once 'uber.php';
      $settings = require_once 'settings.php';
      if ( !isset( $_GET["code"] ) ) {
          setcookie( "AccessToken", "", time() - 3600);
          Header( "Location: https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=".$settings['global']['client_id'].'&redirect_uri=localhost/location.php&client_secret='.$settings['global']['client_secret']);
          die();
      }

  ```
  $result = postKeys("https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token",
      array(
          'client_secret'=>$settings['global']['client_secret'],
          'client_id'=>$settings['global']['client_id'],
          'grant_type'=> 'authorization_code',
          'redirect_uri'=> 'http://localhost/location.php',
          'code'=> $_GET["code"],
          ), array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  );
  // после получения ответа, проверяем на код 200, и если все хорошо, то у нас есть токен
  if ($result["code"]==200) {
      $result["response"]=json_decode($result["response"],true);
      $token=$result["response"]["access_token"];
      $new = new Token($settings);
      $new->setToken($token);
  }else
      echo "не правильный код: ".$result["code"].' '.$result['response'];
  ```